# transaction log restore

Tags: sql-server-2008

I would like to know if I'm understanding this right. My DB backup model is set to FULL. If I perform a full backup at night and transaction log backups every hour after that then I will be able to recover all the data up to the last transaction log backup. Is this statement correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Glad to help...